# Is profiling still possible after SPECTRE was fixed?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, profiling

Since a couple of weeks I'm trying to profile a piece of numerical software and I'm unable to get useful results. 
The code I'm profiling results in a huge function (__attribute__((flatten))) created out of many inlined functions and a few calls to std::exp/std::log/std::pow. This function is located inside a shared library and loaded via dlopen().
I've used

- the google CPU profiler (hangs in the first fork() (interrupted by SIGPROF and restarted and interrupted and...) -- same problem with g++ option -pg)
- linux tool perf (caused a reboot of the machine, I complained and they upgraded the OS (CENTOS 6.5). The results only highlight two assembler instructions out of above mentioned huge function. I don't have permissions to read accurate event sources (*:ppp))
- some old version of vtune (difficult to operate, results are unreliable, no hardware drivers loaded)
- sprof (results do not tell me anything as there is only a single function to profile -- when avoiding to use attribute flatten then the behavior is fully different)

I'm running
CENTOS 6.5
and
g++ (GCC) 5.3.0
I don't have any influence over the version of the OS or the compiler version.
I complained about the ancient OS some weeks ago, and they upgraded me to what I mentioned above.

In some former live I successfully used the google profiler -- when it was working (and not crashing or hanging due to signal handling problems) it provided useful results.

Anybody any comment?
Could all these unclear results be the result of the fixes for SPECTRE?
Do I need to insist, that certain profiling options are enabled on the machine?
Do I need to insist on the vtune drivers loaded?
Do I need to insist on an uptodate copy of vtune installed?
Compile with -fno-omit-frame-pointers?

Comment: What specifically makes you think that your issues have to do with spectre mitigations?

Comment: "omit-frame-pointer" can confuse many debugging and profiling tools, but that's completely orthogonal to spectre concerns.

Comment: "Is profiling still possible after SPECTRE was fixed?" - Note: spectre has not been "*fixed*". Some variations have been *mitigated*, but *fixed*? *No*.

Comment: The results do not tell me anything. Sometimes the function I'm trying to profile consumes only a small percentage and next session a bigger one. And I don't get any information about the lines of code which are expensive (remember two assembly instructions are being highlighted as the hotspots and everything else is blank). The profiling session always works on the same input data, so it ought to be repeatable. Also that google profiler does not yield any consistent results anymore, is from my point of view a hint at spectre mitigation.

Comment: *Maybe* you just don't know how to use your profiling tools correctly *or* don't know how to properly interpret their results. Not saying that's the problem, but it *could* be. For what it's worth; I've been having great success recently with `perf` on my CentOS 7.8 workstation that has all spectre etc mitigations enabled.